# How do I pass SQL a double as a parameter?

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to run this code:

```
Set Lrs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [LastName]" & _
      "From ['Chromebook Registration Form]" & _
      "Where [InventoryNumber] = dbInventoryNumber ")
```

Where "dbInventoryNumber" is a double variable. The field [InventoryNumber] takes a double, but when I run this I get a 3061 Run-time error. Too few arguments. Expected 1.

I know how to pass string variables as parameters, but how do I do it for doubles?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although the `[ ]s` will allow the SQL to evaluate, should include space at end of each continued line so SQL string doesn't run together when compiled. Pass double variable same way as string except don't use apostrophe delimiters. (Date/time field parameters use # delimiter.) Don't put variables within quote marks, concatenate them. Remove apostrophe in front of source (assuming this is not really in source name - advise no spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention). Source name that includes word "Form" sounds like name of a form. Source must be a table or query.

```
Set Lrs = db.OpenRecordset("Select [LastName] " & _
      "From [Chromebook Registration Form] " & _
      "Where [InventoryNumber] = " & dbInventoryNumber)
```